# Como calcular cartões ponto

Tags: java, otimização, calendar

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que condiz ao cálculo de total de horas trabalhadas em cartões pontos, levando em consideração se é redução de hora noturna ou não e, se for, qual é a entrada e a saída noturna.

**O problema é:**

Para calcular o cartão ponto, estou percorrendo entradas e saídas, utilizando *Calendar*, e adicionando minuto a minuto 1 por 1, na entrada e em uma variável auxiliar, como contador.

Quando é para calcular a redução da hora noturna, eu calculo de segundo em segundo e, faço a redução (para quem não sabe, de noite, as horas trabalhadas valem "mais" na proporção de a cada 7 segundos, condiz que você trabalhou 8)

Mas esse método é "muito" lento e, eu tenho que calcular cartões pontos de diversos dias, o que faz a aplicação ficar lenta.

**Minha dúvida:**

Existe um método ou Biblioteca que faça esses cálculos, de maneira otimizada? Ou então, existe uma maneira de fazer esses cálculos mais rápido? (utilizando threads, ou coisa do tipo)

Vou postar o meu código que calcula o total do cartão ponto, comentei ele para melhor compreensão (obs: tem um objeto `cartãoponto` como parâmetro, mas durante o código, dá para entender os atributos dele)

```
public static synchronized String getHor(Cartaoponto c) {
    boolean isNot = c.getIsnoturnoCartaoponto();//verifico se é para reduzir ou não
    String[] entss = c.getEntradasCartaoponto().split("=");//entradas, setado como string porque não existe um valor fixo, e como string posso ir adicionando eternamente
    String[] saiss = c.getSaidasCartaoponto().split("=");//mesma coisa das entradas
    String entra = getAddIn(sdfH.format(c.getAdicionalentradaCartaoponto()), entss);//Verifica se tem que adicionar um "extra" no início do Cartão ponto
    String saia = getAddSai(sdfH.format(c.getAdicionalsaidaCartaoponto()), saiss);//mesma coisa de antes, so que no anterior
    entss = entra.split("=");//seto novamente o valor (já mudado!)
    saiss = saia.split("=");
    Date entNot = c.getEntradanoturnaCartaoponto();//entrada noturna
    Date saiNot = c.getSaidanoturnaCartaoponto();//saída noturna
    Date data = c.getDataCartaoponto();//data em relação ao cartão ponto
    StringTools stT = new StringTools();
    int cont = 0;
    int aux1 = 0, aux2 = 0;
    for (String s : entss) {
        if (!s.trim().equals(":")) {//verifico quantas batidas estão preenchidas
            cont += 1;
        }
        if (s.trim().equals("00:00")) {
            aux1 += 1;
        }
    }
    for (String s : saiss) {//verifico se a batida não é 0,
        if (s.trim().equals("00:00")) {
            aux2 += 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < entss.length; i++) {
        if (!entss[i].trim().equals(":")) {
            if (saiss[i].trim().equals(":")) {//se tiver entrada, mas não tiver saída, retorna erro!
                return "ERRO";
            }
        }
    }
    if (aux1 + aux2 > 4) {//se tiver mais de 4 batidas que é "00:00"
        cont = 0;
    }
    if (cont == 0) {//se não houver batidas (estiver vazio) retorna 0
        return "00:00";
    }
    String[] ents = new String[cont];//seta uma nova variável, com o número de batidas (tirando as vazias)
    String[] saids = new String[cont];
    cont = 0;
    for (String s : entss) {//seta o valor para os Arrays
        if (!s.trim().equals(":")) {
            ents[cont] = s;
            cont += 1;
        }
    }
    cont = 0;
    for (String s : saiss) {
        if (!s.trim().equals(":")) {
            saids[cont] = s;
            cont += 1;
        }
    }
    String a = "";
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfh = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Calendar tot = Calendar.getInstance();
        tot.set(data.getYear(),//total
                data.getMonth(),
                data.getDay(),
                0,
                0,
                0);
        Calendar datIn = Calendar.getInstance();
        datIn.set(tot.get(Calendar.YEAR),//data de Início (para verificar depois, pois pode ser mais que 24h e o Calendar não ajuda nesse quesito)
                tot.get(Calendar.MONDAY),
                tot.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                tot.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                tot.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                tot.get(Calendar.SECOND)
        );
        datIn.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);//millisegundos = 0, porque tem verificações e isso já me deu dor de cabeça
        tot.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, aux2);

        for (int i = 0; i < ents.length; i++) {//laço de repetição entre as batidas
            if (saids[i].trim().equals(":")) {//se a saída estiver vazia
                if (ents[i].trim().equals(":")) {//se a entrada estiver vazia, vá para o próximo (mesmo tendo a verificação anterior, resolvi ter certeza)
                    continue;
                } else {//se tiver entrada, mas não tiver saída, retorna erro
                    return "ERRO";
                }
            }
            Calendar saiNotu = Calendar.getInstance();//saida noturna
            saiNotu.setTime(saiNot);
            saiNotu.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            Calendar entNotu = Calendar.getInstance();//entrada noturna
            entNotu.setTime(entNot);
            entNotu.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            if (entNotu.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 00 && entNotu.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < saiNotu.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) {
                entNotu.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);//seto assim, pois na lei brasileira, a entrada é 22:00 do dia x, e a saída é 05:00 do dia x+1
            }
            Calendar sai = Calendar.getInstance();//saída
            sai.setTime(data);
            sai.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sdfh.parse(saids[i]).getHours());
            sai.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sdfh.parse(saids[i]).getMinutes());
            sai.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            if (sai.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 00 && sai.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < saiNotu.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) {
                sai.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
            }
            Calendar ent = Calendar.getInstance();//entrada
            ent.setTime(data);
            ent.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sdfh.parse(ents[i]).getHours());
            ent.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sdfh.parse(ents[i]).getMinutes());
            ent.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            if (ent.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 00 && ent.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < saiNotu.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) {
                ent.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
            }
            while (ent.after(sai)) {
                sai.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            }//se a saída for antes da entrada (como 23:30 e 00:00 por exemplo) adiciona 1 à saída
            int aux = 0;
            while (!ent.equals(sai)) {//percorre o tempo (entre ent e sai)
                Date entras = sdfH.parse(sdfH.format(ent.getTime()));//fiz isso para ajudar na verificação
                Date entraNot = sdfH.parse(sdfH.format(entNot.getTime()));
                int day2 = entraNot.getDate() + 1;
                String day1 = String.valueOf(day2);
                if (day2 < 10) {
                    day1 = "0" + day1;
                }
                Date saiaNot = sdfHd.parse(day1 + "-" + sdfH.format(saiNot.getTime()));//até aqui, foi pelo seguinte quesito:
                //A entrada e saída, pode dar um erro de verificação se eu deixar para o dia atual, por isso tenho
                //que deixar toda hora como válida, ou seja, se fosse sem essa verificação anterior, quando tivesse
                //03:00 até 06:00 ele ia contar como hora normal, não hora reduzida, mas já se tivesse
                //22:00 até as 00:00 ele funcionava, por isso eu tive que fazer essa "gambiarra"
                if (entras.before(entraNot)) {//se entrada for antes da entrada noturna
                    day2 = entraNot.getDate() - 1;
                    day1 = String.valueOf(day2);
                    if (day2 < 10) {
                        day1 = "0" + day1;
                    }
                    entraNot = sdfHd.parse(day1 + "-" + sdfH.format(entNot.getTime()));
                    day2 = saiaNot.getDate() - 1;
                    day1 = String.valueOf(day2);
                    if (day2 < 10) {
                        day1 = "0" + day1;
                    }
                    saiaNot = sdfHd.parse(day1 + "-" + sdfH.format(saiNot.getTime()));
                }//removo 1 dia da entrada e da saída noturna
                if ((entras.after(entraNot) || entras.equals(entraNot)) && entras.before(saiaNot)) {//se a entrada for entre entrada noturna e a saída noturna
                    if (isNot) {//calculo o total como hora noturna reduzida se o cartãoponto pedir isso
                        ent.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
                        aux += 1;
                        if (aux == 7) {
                            tot.add(Calendar.SECOND, 8);
                            aux = 0;
                        }
                    } else {//senão, adiciono minuto a minuto
                        ent.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
                        tot.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
                    }
                } else {//se não estiver dentro da hora noturna (fora de entrada noturna e saída noturna)
                    ent.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);//adiciona minuto a minuto
                    tot.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        boolean teste = false;//verificação de erro
        int multiplicador = stT.dataDiff(datIn.getTime(), tot.getTime());//multiplicador de dias (pega a diferença de data entre data de Início e o total)
        if (multiplicador < 0) {//se o multiplicador for menor que 0 (data de Início for depois da data final) (deu erro, por isso o teste)
            multiplicador = multiplicador * (-1);//multiplicador fica normal, teste=true
            teste = true;
        }
        multiplicador = multiplicador * 24;//multiplica os dias para ter as horas
        multiplicador = multiplicador + tot.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);//adiciona o total de horas ao dia
        if (multiplicador > 24) {//verificação de erro também, porque se for mais que 24, o teste é true.
            multiplicador = multiplicador - 24;
        }
        if (multiplicador >= 10 && multiplicador <= 25) {//daqui para frente eu deixo o total no formato ("HH:mm:ss") para o SimpleDateFormat
//para logo em seguida arredondar os segundos para ficar no formato ("HH:mm")
            if (tot.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 10) {
                if (tot.get(Calendar.SECOND) < 10) {
                    a = String.valueOf(multiplicador)
                            + ":0"
                            + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                            + ":0"
                            + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                } else {
                    a = String.valueOf(multiplicador)
                            + ":0"
                            + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                            + ":"
                            + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                }
            } else if (tot.get(Calendar.SECOND) < 10) {
                a = String.valueOf(multiplicador)
                        + ":"
                        + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                        + ":0"
                        + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            } else {
                a = String.valueOf(multiplicador)
                        + ":"
                        + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                        + ":"
                        + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            }
            a = String.valueOf(multiplicador)
                    + ":"
                    + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                    + ":"
                    + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        } else if (multiplicador < 10) {
            if (tot.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 10) {
                if (tot.get(Calendar.SECOND) < 10) {
                    a = "0" + String.valueOf(multiplicador)
                            + ":0"
                            + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                            + ":0"
                            + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                } else {
                    a = "0" + String.valueOf(multiplicador)
                            + ":0"
                            + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                            + ":"
                            + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                }
            } else if (tot.get(Calendar.SECOND) < 10) {
                a = "0" + String.valueOf(multiplicador)
                        + ":"
                        + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                        + ":0"
                        + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            } else {
                a = "0" + String.valueOf(multiplicador)
                        + ":"
                        + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                        + ":"
                        + String.valueOf(tot.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            }
        }
        a = arredondaSegundos(a);//aqui ele arredonda os segundos, se for maior que 30, para cima, senão, para baixo
        if (teste) {//se deu erro, posta o valor do total
            System.out.println("A: " + a);
        }
    } catch (Exception E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
    }
    return a;//retorna o total
}
```

Comment: A lentidão ocorre porque você está usando strings para armazenar tempo e tem que ficar convertendo para fazer os cálculos, use um ArrayList<Date> para armazenar as entradas.

Comment: Não acho que seja, pois faço 2 ou 3 conversões de um lado para o outro, enquanto tenho que percorrer toda a batida segundo por segundo ou minuto por minuto, creio que uma maneira de reduzir isso seria utilizando o _JodaTime_  e "removendo" o máximo de batidas possivel para depois começar a percorrer as batidas restantes. Mas mesmo assim, é uma ideia e já é uma otimização a mais, mesmo que pequeno. Eu utilizo `JPA`, então preciso de uma classe entidade. No banco de dados coloca que tipo de dado para relacionar o ArrayList? (só para esclarecer, eu utilizo `MySQL` como banco de dados)

Comment: lembrando também que eu faço as classes de entidade pelo gerador automático que o netBeans disponibiliza

Comment: Nesse caso seria melhor  você criar uma tabela separada para armazenar as batidas. Eu recomendo criar uma tabela com as colunas entrada e saída.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que o melhor jeito seria:

1. Descubra a quantidade de horas trabalhadas no período noturno (sem redução)
2. Transfore para decimal. **Ex:** 3h25m fica 3,42 (25/60=0,42)
3. Multiplique esse valor por 1,142857142857143. Esse é o valor da relação entre a hora normal e a hora noturna dada por 60/52,5: **Ex:** 3,42*1,142857142857143 = 3,908571
4. Converta de volta para hh:mm: **Ex:** 0,908571*60 = 54,5142 = 3h:55m

Comment: eu pensei em fazer desse jeito, mas não funciona, porque esse método é geral, então eu uso ele para outros métodos também, e tem alguns que eu tenho que filtrar algumas coisas a partir de determinado ponto, o que complica um pouco

Comment: Cara não é por que "complica um pouco"'que está errado, algumas vezes (não sempre) para deixar o algoritmo mais rápido teremos que criar rotinas complexas, então caso você não tente o que a resposta acima apontou (apesar de fazer sentido), você não pode falar que não funciona.

Comment: Eu sei que faz sentido, mas realmente, fazer dessa maneira resolve meu problema em partes, mas cria outros problemas, que eu teria de recorrer ao método antigo para continuar, o que não adianta muito, vendo que quero otimizar o sistema, então realmente, funciona mas de maneira deficiente, ou seja, resolve parte do problema apenas